# my.cnf php.ini for large sites

Tags: php, mysql

I have an application that does the following:

- Gets rows from a mysql table (sometimes there might be over 10,000 or so rows to process)
- Send data from these rows to a third party site

And it also does the following:

- Every second, there is a daemon that creates a process that handles processing for an entity.
- So when the entity is going to take place, a daemon uses the nohup php command to execute php code that handles that entity.

I want to make sure the application is efficient and works even when there are large rows in the database or a lot of php nohups to execute.

What settings should I set in my.cnf and php.ini and httpd.conf that allows large sites to scale? I know this might depend on a lot of situations, but can you guys please help me figure out how I would know what to set for these settings?..

Answer (score 0):

- MySQL - I would recommend using [Percona](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/) vs vanilla MySQL. Their documentation has several references to my.cnf settings you can tweak to improve performance, reliability and stability.
- PHP - PHPLens has an [older article](http://phplens.com/lens/php-book/optimizing-debugging-php.php), but a lot of the information still holds true, as well as some of the proposed .ini setting changes.